# XPath - Drop Down Boxes

Tags: xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

I'm new to the Selenium automation testing. Trying to find the Xpath of two drop down boxes in our web application but no luck yet; Here is the HTML code of both;
In below HTML, I am trying to create the Xpath using Attribute @Placeholder which is the unique one; rest all common in both but failed to get it correctly; Each drop down has set of values and I am trying to get these values using "Select" Tried "Contains", "Start With" methods too.

Request you to provide your kind suggestions and tips.

```html
   <input class="form-control bootstrap-typeahead-input-main" type="text" placeholder="Alpha Type" autocomplete="off" value="" style="background-color: transparent; display: block; position: relative; z-index: 1;">

   <input class="form-control bootstrap-typeahead-input-main" type="text" placeholder="Beta Type" autocomplete="off" value="" style="background-color: transparent; display: block; position: relative; z-index: 1;">
```

**Here is the latest combination I am making;**

```html
@FindBy(how= How.XPATH, using="//input[contains(@placeholder='Alpha Type')]")
@FindBy(how= How.XPATH, using="//input[contains(@placeholder='Beta Type')]")
```

**Using Select after finding the Xpath to get values of drop down;**

```html
  Select drpAlphaType = new Select(AlphaType);
  drpEnqType.selectByValue("XYZ");
```

Comment: Did you try to add a pause after clicking on box? Which error are you getting?

Comment: you said it is dropdown but your html says type="text" ?

Comment: What you are trying with Select method, There should must be <select> tag available in HTML Source, Then it will select <Select> dropdown value. 

HTML which you have shared, it containing text type. Share correct HTML which belongs to drop down code.

Comment: @Andrei: Yes, I have tried to add a pause/wait after click.

Comment: Prany: Yes, its a drop down Xpath which contains multiple values but I don't find any <Select> for the drop down values. I am not sure if I can add/edit the whole html again in the same thread.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to select a value from a drop down and based on that the next drop down enable different values (Based on our selection). The Xpath shown above is the working fine while navigating to the exact drop down but values are not getting selected as they are in different place in a seperate DIVtag .......... i.e. <DIV > ul > li[3] > a >  span > strong (Under this I have value of drop down whcih needs to be selected)

Answer (score 0):

XPath's `contains()` function is a ***substring*** test – not what you want here.

Change

```
//input[contains(@placeholder='Alpha Type')]
```

to

```
//input[@placeholder='Alpha Type']
```

to select all `input` elements with a `@placeholder` attribute value of `"Alpha Type"`.

Comment: Earlier, I had tried this as well //input[@placeholder='Alpha Type'] what you suggested, but it also didn't work. Any other suggestion, please?

Comment: Yes, I suggest that you never just say "didn't work" but rather elaborate with details including the specific error message received.  You may have multiple problems, but you can at least know that you're closer as this XPath does exactly what this answer says it does.

Comment: When I tried what you are suggesting, it's throwing an exception as below; org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@placeholder='Alpha Type')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@placeholder='Alpha Type')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Remove the extraneous `)`.

Comment: Apologies. Earlier, it was a typo with ")". Now, having an actual error as below; org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"

Answer (score 0):

You are using `select`, but it is wrong, because according your error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"
```

This element is an input. So try to handle with it like this:

```
@FindBy(how= How.XPATH, using="//input[@placeholder='Alpha Type']") private WebElement alphaType;
@FindBy(how= How.XPATH, using="//input[@placeholder='Beta Type']") private WebElement betaType;

WebDriverWait waitAlpha = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5); // 5 seconds
waitAlpha.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(alphaType)); //wait until element clickable
alphaType.click();
alphaType.sendKeys("your string"); //write 'your string' in input field

WebDriverWait waitBeta = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
waitBeta.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(betaType));
betaType.click();
betaType.sendKeys("your string");
```

After this should dropdown a list of values, which should be located separately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support and tips. The issue is resolved with one additional step which I have added. It was correctly pointed out earlier that the Xpath was pointing to an input element but "Select" was expected

i.e. org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"

To try alternatives, I have dropped the idea of using "Select" class but to simply input the values. While adding two XPATHs (One for the input/drop-down field and another one for the value in that drop down) and clicking both in a sequence. Now, my code looks like this;

`AlphaType.click(); 
AlphaType.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='home-tabs-pane-0']/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a/span")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);`

Same goes for the other one i.e. Beta Type. Please share thoughts if there is further improved way of doing this.